# Unity project upgrade : Upgrade project from Unity4 to Unity5 Getcomponent issue when build

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm upgrade my unity game project from UNITY4.7.2 to UNITY2019.1.7f1 everything WORK ON UNITY EDITOR(UNITY2019.1.7f1) but after I'm build project to iPhoneX game isn't work for some function eg.FindGameObjectWithTag, GetComponent I'm check in code and found getcomponent is not work at calling time

I'm already solved this by add spawnArea prefab to inspector and call them but for another function that use GetComponent still not work.

please anybody suggest me about problem whem we call getcomponent problem.

I'm looking around my code, unity console and search in google too, and assume FindGameObjectWithTag, GetComponent and another code kind like those 2 have problem when upgrade unity4 to unity2019:

```
 spawnPoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(TagManager.spawnArea).transform;

    if (currentVehicle != null) {
        if(bigTruck)
            DestroyImmediate(currentVehicle.transform.parent.gameObject);
        else
            DestroyImmediate(currentVehicle.gameObject);
    }

    GameObject vehicle = Instantiate(vehiclePrefabs[GameManager.instance.selectedCar], spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
    currentVehicle = vehicle.GetComponent<BaseVehicle>();
    if (currentVehicle == null) {
        currentVehicle = vehicle.GetComponentInChildren<BaseVehicle>();
        bigTruck = true;
    } else {
        bigTruck = false;
    }
    playerCamera.target = currentVehicle.transform;
    playerCamera.vehicleFront = currentVehicle.transform.Find("Front");
```

In unity console when I use debug build they show "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." but I'm look around my code and not found any object that null reference, I test by compare with null eg.

```
if (currentVehicle == null) {
  Debug.Log("currentVehicle is null");
}
```

Comment: what's in the basevehicle

Comment: there is code for check kind of car